# Need suggestions about slower loading time of product page because of configrable swatch

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, swatches

Is anyone can help me with this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly happens when you have lots of option for configurable attribute which slow down the page

so for that

Copy

`/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php` to

`/app/code/local/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php`

go to this code

```
 $optionLabels = array_map(function ($value) {
   return array_map('Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data::normalizeKey',    $value);
}, $optionLabels);
```

and put this code before its parent foreach loop and you will get some improvement

Answer (score 0):

can you add some informations about your hardware setup 
e.h. php version, memory+cpu of database server, memory+cpu of php server,
total amount of products, used cache system?

Anyway:

Loading configproducts takes a bit of performance. You can thinkabout of using customoptions or split your configuratable product and use filternavigation with colors. e.g. in this store
http://www.shophudabeauty.com/product-category/make-up/lip-contour/?v=3a52f3c22ed6
They use the category (layer) to find your correct product. On productdetail you do not need to make any color selections.

cheers